# Vertex JS and Redis Sentinel Support

Tags: javascript, redis, vert.x, redis-sentinel

Does Vertx 3.5.0 supports Redis Sentinel or not? Any other ways to achieve it?

I have a Master and Slave Architecture in Redis, where I have failover implementation concepts. I can achieve this using NodeJS and Java, but while switching on to vertx-js I am unable to get the sentinel Connections.

Is there any updates regarding Sentinel Support for Vertx?

Comment: Could you share your code? At first sight, it should work, because it communicates with the redis through the network and it is not relative to language/library/framework you use

Comment: Are you sure it gets the current Master from the sentinel ??

Answer (score 0):

As of 3.5.0 there is a [Redis Sentinel](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-redis-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/redis/sentinel/RedisSentinel.java) implementation. This was contributed by the community and hasn't been extensively tested so it is not referenced in the docs. If you have experience with it you could help verify it and we can then add proper references to the docs.

<s>Also note that this support is currently not polyglot (so you're stuck with Java at the moment).</s>

There is Support for polyglot sentinel in the [master branch](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-redis-client/commit/4d29d186d78768781d77ceb13223179ba843f2c4). If you're brave enough, please test it! :)

Comment: Thanks Lopes for the reply, was waiting for that.I am using JS as my Language. can i built a jar using Pure Java or Java+Vertx to connect redis-sentinel using that jar file in my JS Program ? @Paulo Lopes

Comment: Yes that would be possible `Java.type()` is your friend https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions